# Count number occurrences of an element in LeanFT

Tags: c#, count, leanft

**is there any LeanFT method that returns the number of an element?** I wish to use it instead of the `exists()` method. Something like the following:

```
if(PageX.Node.closeTabButton.count() > 0)
   {
    ...
    Treatement
    ...
   }
```

I wanted to check if a type of bouton (Close Tab Button) exists on the page before starting a treatment, so I put that as a condition:

```
if(PageX.Node.closeTabButton.exists())
   {
    ...
    Treatement
    ...
   }
```

the `exists()` method seems not work because there is more than one `closeTabButton` elements on the page, that's why I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single object, you should use the parent's [FindChildren](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uftdev/en/2021-2022/NetSDKReference/Content/NetSDKReference/HP.LFT.SDK%7EHP.LFT.SDK.ITestObject%7EFindChildren.html) with the description, then you can see how many elements exist.